# Accessibility in iOS: providing a brief description of a screen

Tags: ios, swift, accessibility, voiceover

I am not very experienced in Accessibility, and I'm learning some basics, specially related to `VoiceOver` feature.

I was wondering: is it a good practice to provide a brief overall description of what a screen is showing when it is loaded? If so, how could I do this? I have read about the `accessibilityLabel` property for specific controls, but you need to tap on them to hear it.

Comment: Well, there is the whole section for VoiceOver there. If you want, you can always play audio on `viewWillAppear`, but to be honest, I've never seen that in `Accessibility` apps.

Answer (score 1):

No, providing overall description of a page to screen reader users is not a common or popularly recommended practice.

You may be aware that the Accessibility tree is developed from the DOM tree. The browsers use the DOM in order to populate what the Accessibility tree contains for AT. So coding your page the right way is sufficient to be accessible and to provide relevant information to Screen reader users.

Clear and unique page title, rightly assigned heading levels, conveying semantics of the web page correctly, using native elements so that they work predictably and handle keyboard focus by default, ensuring that the elements in the page have correct accessible roles, states and properties, and that we specify accessible names and descriptions etc. are some of the key points to keep in mind while coding the page.

Having said that, if there's any complex functionality within the page that needs help text or additional instructions to make sense for Screen reader users, then  providing off-screen text or aria techniques within the close proximity of the context may be useful.